# duplicate list items when using .replace() function

Tags: python, string, list, replace

```
lst = ['123,456', '"hello"', '345,678', '"bye"']
def main():
    new_lst = []
    for item in lst: 
        #print item
        new_lst.append(item.replace(',','***'))
        new_lst.append(item.replace('\"', ''))
    return new_lst

print main()
```

This is quite puzzling to me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I know it's a very stupid mistake but it's not clicking for me. I don't know why I get an output of:

```
['123***456', '123,456', '"hello"', 'hello', '345***678', '345,678', '"bye"', 'bye']
```

What I was hoping was for:

```
['123***456', 'hello', '345***678', 'bye']
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the same string twice, with two different replacements. You should chain the `replace`s like this

```
new_lst.append(item.replace(',','***').replace('\"', ''))
```

Even better, you can use a list comprehension here, like this

```
return [item.replace(',','***').replace('\"', '') for item in lst]
```

Comment: I didn't know Python could accept two replaces in one statement. Thanks!

Comment: `replace` isn't a statement, it's a method of string objects. Since it is a method of string objects and also *returns* a string, you can chain them together to your heart's content: `s.replace(a,b).replace(c,d).replace(x,y)...`